# Greasepencil strokes disappear behind geometry when rendering

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, grease-pencil

I am wokring on a project using Greasepencil to add detail to 3D geometry.

Everything looks fine in the viewport, but as soon as I render, some of the strokes that are close to 3D objects start to disappear behind them, while others just appear very jagged.

What is the difference between the grease pencil rendering in the viewport and the render? And is there any way I can make grease pencil render behave like it does in the viewport?

It just seem that when rendering Blender calculates the depth of the grease pencil strokes differently than in viewport.

In the past I've usually fixed this by moving the strokes further away from the surfaces, but this is not optimal, especially when the object is not going to be viewed from just one angle.

Viewport rendering is not a great solution for me because I intend to do some compositing in Blender.

This is how the grease pencil objects look rendered:
[image: rendered_greaspencil]

And this is what it should, and does look like in the viewport:
[image: viewport_greasepencil]

Comment: it might be the denoising try unchecking denoising and see if the lines render properly?

Answer (score 0):

2 years later, and it seems to still be an issue. However I think I found a culprit. It could be that the camera size too small, or the camera in general is too far away. It's usually at 36mm, and in my case had it in 11mm, and the same issue happened to me, but after returning to it's original size, I got to work again. But then I decided to move back, and the issue came up again. So yeah, that's the only things that comes to mind

Edit: What I ended up doing in my case, was to convert the GP detail into mesh and then use the lineart modifier to bring them back, and somehow it works fine at far and close distance